# Why is Marvell SATA 3 storage interface not recommended for SSD?

Tags: ssd, motherboard, sata

I am planning to add an SATA 3 SSD drive to my computer which has a Gigabyte UD7 motherboard ([link](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3527))(Socket 1366, Intel X58 chipset). The SSD drive will be used purely as an OS drive for Win8.1 x64. The UD7 motherboard has a Marvell 9128 chip for SATA 3 ports, but apparently no native Intel SATA 3 ports.

Some of the forums say that the Marvell 9128 chip should be avoided for use with SSD drive running on SATA 3. So my question is this: Does any one know why the Marvell SATA3 ports should be avoided?

Any help would be appreciated.

-Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All external SATA3 chips should be avoided. They often have slow detecting rate which slows down boot. Also they are often connected with PCI-E x1 bandwith/lanes and can't provide the full speed.

Here is also a topic dealing with the issues:

http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2227791

Play a bit with the configuration, maybe you have luck and it is a bit better compared to the Intel SATA2 ports.